# sequence Rank in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get sequence number in mssql. Please see below.

There is a table.

```
UserID     Score      TeamID
------------------------------
1          100         1
2          200         1
3          500         2
4          600         2
5          700         2
6          1000        3
```

I would like to sort by total score group by team. see below

```
RankID       UserID        Score     TeamID      TotalScore
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            3             500       2           1800           
1            4             600       2           1800
1            5             700       2           1800  
2            6             1000      3           1000
3            1             100       1           300
3            2             200       1           300
```

I want to code only one sql query. Help me someone how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Let's say they are one table.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
;WITH TotalScore AS (
  SELECT UserID, Score, TeamID,
    SUM(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY TeamID) AS TotalScore
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalScore DESC) AS RankID,
  UserID, Score, TeamID, TotalScore   
FROM TotalScore
ORDER BY TotalScore DESC, Score
```

The Common Table Expression used calculates the total score per `TeamID` using windowed version of `SUM`. Using `DENSE_RANK` together with this calculated field we can easily generate the required `RankID`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY i.TotalScore DESC) AS RankID
,A.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
     UserID
    ,Score
    ,TeamID
    ,(SELECT SUM(Score) FROM yourTable tb2 WHERE tb2.TeamID = tb1.TeamID) AS TotalScore
FROM yourTable tb1
) A
ORDER BY A.TotalScore DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a Try with below,

```
Select DENSE_RANK() over(Order by (Select Sum(Score) from @tablename V where V.TeamID=T.TeamID ) desc )RankID
,*,
Sum(Score) over(Partition by TeamID) TotalScore from @tablename T
order by DENSE_RANK() over(Order by (Select Sum(Score) from @tablename V where V.TeamID=T.TeamID ) desc )
```

Dense Rank in the 'Order by' to sort the results by RANK Id and the same is used in Select statement, Subquery in the Dense Rank will rank based on the sum(Score) for a TeamID